# picklist Value deployment Issue

Tags: apex, deployment, package.xml

I retrieve the Record type using Package.xml.Its having Available picklist value

```
<!--<values>
<fullName> Mandatory%3A K-12</fullName>
<default>false</default>
</values>-->
```

but when i am deploying in other sandbox i am getting below error

> Lead.ABCRecortype  Record Type     Picklist value: Mandatory%3A K-12 in
>   picklist: Industry not found

Comment: Was that the first error or several errors down in a list of errors?